# Как отобразить несколько шейдеров сканера в Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d, шейдеры

Есть шейдер топографического сканера от https://youtu.be/OKoNp2RqE9A. Вот сам код шейдера:

```
// Upgrade NOTE: replaced 'mul(UNITY_MATRIX_MVP,*)' with 'UnityObjectToClipPos(*)'

Shader "Hidden/ScannerEffect"
{
    Properties
    {
        _MainTex("Texture", 2D) = "white" {}
        _DetailTex("Texture", 2D) = "white" {}
        _ScanDistance("Scan Distance", float) = 0
        _ScanWidth("Scan Width", float) = 10
        _LeadSharp("Leading Edge Sharpness", float) = 10
        _LeadColor("Leading Edge Color", Color) = (1, 1, 1, 0)
        _MidColor("Mid Color", Color) = (1, 1, 1, 0)
        _TrailColor("Trail Color", Color) = (1, 1, 1, 0)
        _HBarColor("Horizontal Bar Color", Color) = (0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0)
    }
    SubShader
    {
        // No culling or depth
        Cull Off ZWrite Off ZTest Always

        Pass
        {
            CGPROGRAM
            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag
            
            #include "UnityCG.cginc"

            struct VertIn
            {
                float4 vertex : POSITION;
                float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
                float4 ray : TEXCOORD1;
            };

            struct VertOut
            {
                float4 vertex : SV_POSITION;
                float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
                float2 uv_depth : TEXCOORD1;
                float4 interpolatedRay : TEXCOORD2;
            };

            float4 _MainTex_TexelSize;
            float4 _CameraWS;

            VertOut vert(VertIn v)
            {
                VertOut o;
                o.vertex = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);
                o.uv = v.uv.xy;
                o.uv_depth = v.uv.xy;

                #if UNITY_UV_STARTS_AT_TOP
                if (_MainTex_TexelSize.y < 0)
                    o.uv.y = 1 - o.uv.y;
                #endif              

                o.interpolatedRay = v.ray;

                return o;
            }

            sampler2D _MainTex;
            sampler2D _DetailTex;
            sampler2D_float _CameraDepthTexture;
            float4 _WorldSpaceScannerPos;
            float _ScanDistance;
            float _ScanWidth;
            float _LeadSharp;
            float4 _LeadColor;
            float4 _MidColor;
            float4 _TrailColor;
            float4 _HBarColor;

            float4 horizBars(float2 p)
            {
                return 1 - saturate(round(abs(frac(p.y * 100) * 2)));
            }

            float4 horizTex(float2 p)
            {
                return tex2D(_DetailTex, float2(p.x * 30, p.y * 40));
            }

            half4 frag (VertOut i) : SV_Target
            {
                half4 col = tex2D(_MainTex, i.uv);

                float rawDepth = DecodeFloatRG(tex2D(_CameraDepthTexture, i.uv_depth));
                float linearDepth = Linear01Depth(rawDepth);
                float4 wsDir = linearDepth * i.interpolatedRay;
                float3 wsPos = _WorldSpaceCameraPos + wsDir;
                half4 scannerCol = half4(0, 0, 0, 0);

                float dist = distance(wsPos, _WorldSpaceScannerPos);

                if (dist < _ScanDistance && dist > _ScanDistance - _ScanWidth && linearDepth < 1)
                {
                    float diff = 1 - (_ScanDistance - dist) / (_ScanWidth);
                    half4 edge = lerp(_MidColor, _LeadColor, pow(diff, _LeadSharp));
                    scannerCol = lerp(_TrailColor, edge, diff) + horizBars(i.uv) * _HBarColor;
                    scannerCol *= diff;
                }

                return col + scannerCol;
            }
            ENDCG
        }
    }
}
```

А так же скрипт который вызывает сам эффект:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

[ExecuteInEditMode]
public class ScannerEffectDemo : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform ScannerOrigin;
    public Material EffectMaterial;
    public float ScanDistance;
    public float ScanDecreaseTime;

    private Camera _camera;

    // Demo Code
    [HideInInspector]
    public bool _scanning;
    public bool _canScanningObjectsCollide = true;
    Scannable[] _scannables;

    void Start()
    {
        _scannables = FindObjectsOfType<Scannable>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (_scanning)
        {
            ScanDistance += Time.deltaTime * ScanDecreaseTime;
            if (_canScanningObjectsCollide)
            {
                foreach (Scannable s in _scannables)
                {
                    if (Mathf.RoundToInt(Vector3.Distance(ScannerOrigin.position, s.transform.position)) == Mathf.RoundToInt(ScanDistance))
                        s.Ping();
                }
            }
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.C))
        {
            _canScanningObjectsCollide = true;
            _scanning = true;
            ScanDistance = 0;
        }

        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            _canScanningObjectsCollide = true;
            _scanning = true;
            ScanDistance = 0;
        }
    }
    // End Demo Code

    void OnEnable()
    {
        _camera = GetComponent<Camera>();
        _camera.depthTextureMode = DepthTextureMode.Depth;
    }

    [ImageEffectOpaque]
    void OnRenderImage(RenderTexture src, RenderTexture dst)
    {
        EffectMaterial.SetVector("_WorldSpaceScannerPos", ScannerOrigin.position);
        EffectMaterial.SetFloat("_ScanDistance", ScanDistance);
        RaycastCornerBlit(src, dst, EffectMaterial);
    }

    void RaycastCornerBlit(RenderTexture source, RenderTexture dest, Material mat)
    {
        // Compute Frustum Corners
        float camFar = _camera.farClipPlane;
        float camFov = _camera.fieldOfView;
        float camAspect = _camera.aspect;

        float fovWHalf = camFov * 0.5f;

        Vector3 toRight = _camera.transform.right * Mathf.Tan(fovWHalf * Mathf.Deg2Rad) * camAspect;
        Vector3 toTop = _camera.transform.up * Mathf.Tan(fovWHalf * Mathf.Deg2Rad);

        Vector3 topLeft = (_camera.transform.forward - toRight + toTop);
        float camScale = topLeft.magnitude * camFar;

        topLeft.Normalize();
        topLeft *= camScale;

        Vector3 topRight = (_camera.transform.forward + toRight + toTop);
        topRight.Normalize();
        topRight *= camScale;

        Vector3 bottomRight = (_camera.transform.forward + toRight - toTop);
        bottomRight.Normalize();
        bottomRight *= camScale;

        Vector3 bottomLeft = (_camera.transform.forward - toRight - toTop);
        bottomLeft.Normalize();
        bottomLeft *= camScale;

        // Custom Blit, encoding Frustum Corners as additional Texture Coordinates
        RenderTexture.active = dest;

        mat.SetTexture("_MainTex", source);

        GL.PushMatrix();
        GL.LoadOrtho();

        mat.SetPass(0);

        GL.Begin(GL.QUADS);

        GL.MultiTexCoord2(0, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        GL.MultiTexCoord(1, bottomLeft);
        GL.Vertex3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

        GL.MultiTexCoord2(0, 1.0f, 0.0f);
        GL.MultiTexCoord(1, bottomRight);
        GL.Vertex3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

        GL.MultiTexCoord2(0, 1.0f, 1.0f);
        GL.MultiTexCoord(1, topRight);
        GL.Vertex3(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

        GL.MultiTexCoord2(0, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        GL.MultiTexCoord(1, topLeft);
        GL.Vertex3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

        GL.End();
        GL.PopMatrix();
    }
}
```

При попытке вызвать скрипт два раза, эффект просто начинается заного, а не создаётся новый. Я очень далёк от шейдеров, и прошу помочь мне. Как сделать что бы сканер не начинался заного, а создавался новый эффект (Что бы скажем было отображено сразу 2 таких эффекта в разных точках).

Comment: Вопрос мне тоже очень интересен, сам сейчас ищу на него ответ! Готов открыть конкурс на этот вопрос как только откроется возможность!

Comment: Везет тебе, LZLZZ) Открыл для тебя еще один конкурс с наградой по-больше

Comment: удивительно, спасибо

Comment: видимо нужно идти на англоязычный SO

Comment: Мы сделали всё что могли, если найдете ответ, просьба попробовать раскрыть ответ в данном вопросе)

Comment: Хорошо, попробую